# Infinity scrolling (will_paginate) в view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

ConversationsController:

```
def index
  nil_conversation!

  @profiles = Profile.all.where.not(id: current_profile)
  @conversations = Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages).find(session[:conversations])
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  <%= render 'conversation', conversation: conversation, profile: current_profile %>
<% end %>
```

_conversation.html.erb:

```
<div id="listing-infinite-scrolling">
  <%= @many = conversation.messages.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) %>
  <%= render @many, profile: profile %>
</div>

<div id="paginate-infinite-scrolling">
  <% will_paginate @many %>
</div>
```

В примере данного гема присутствует ссылка на данную view с параметром страницы:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],
                       per_page: 12).order('created_at DESC')

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

Нужно в данную строку передавать параметр page: `<%= @many = messages.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) %>`

Comment: Хэлпер will_paginate принимает в качестве аргумента коллекцию, по которой будет осуществляются навигация. Причем не просто коллекцию, ее следует обработать методом paginate() в контроллере @messages = Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages).find(session[:conversations]).messages.paginate(page: params[:page])

Comment: При добавлении в метод index выдает ошибку: undefined method `messages' for []:Array

Comment: А... у вас messages в паршиле вызывается? Тогда придется метод paginate() туда двигать - он должен обработать коллекцию messages, которая потом передается will_paginate. Но вообще лучше реорганизовать приложение так, чтобы в представлениях не было логики. У вас несколько постраничных навигаций на одной странице?

Comment: Да, так и есть. При выборе пользователя диалога создается сессию и рендерится переписка `var conversations = $('#conversations-list');
var conversation = conversations.find("[data-conversation-id='" + "<%= @conversation.id %>" + "']");
conversations.append("<%= j(render 'conversations/conversation', conversation: @conversation, profile: current_profile) %>");`. В дальнейшем рендерятся сообщения. Все это происходит в методе index с помощью jquery.

Comment: Возможно, вместо params[:page] я бы мог обрататься к переменной с помощью jquery?